# trying to replace Nan value in a column . ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

Tags: pandas

I am grouping by sex and want to fill the mean age for the Nan values in the age column and getting Columns must be same length as key error. What should i do to correct my error

I am expecting the mean age of the female  and male to be replaced in the Nan values of the age column.

My code from jupyter:

[image]

```
df['Age']=df.groupby('Sex').transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

Comment: Your dataframe probably has more than two columns, so you cannot assign `Age` to the output of the right hand side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you provide a reproducible example, i would have validated and shared the resulted

```
COL_FOR_MEAN = # specify the column name for mean

df.groupby('Sex')[COL_FOR_MEAN].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))

# if column is age then

df['Age']=df.groupby('Sex')['Age'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```